# how to scrape the first element of multiple existing elements / beautifulsoup / python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I try to scrape an ID element of an html code. it exists twice and everytime I print it, I get it twice. this is how I scrape it:

```
for review in soup.find_all("div", {"class": "reviewContainer"}):
    for review2 in review.findAll(True, {'id':True}):
        if len(review2) > 0:
            userid = review2['id']
            print(userid)
        else:
            userid = "N/A"
            print(userid)
```

Output:

```
ID_123  
ID_123  
ID_456  
ID_456
```

I tried to add "review2['id'].next_element" to just get the first coming element but I get an error. is there a solution, how I can get the first found element, instead of getting it twice?

Comment: How does the html look like? 99% it will not be the case, but just to make sure.

Comment: You could assemble an exclusion list. Have every ID appended to a list and create a conditional checking whether the ID is in the list or not (append to list after conditional).

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a conditional check to see if you've already found that userid before:

```
    for review in soup.find_all("div", {"class": "reviewContainer"}):
        userid_found = []
        for review2 in review.findAll(True, {'id':True}):
            if len(review2) > 0:
                userid = review2['id']
                if userid not in userid_found:
                    userid_found.append(userid)
                    print(userid)
            else:
                userid = "N/A"
                print(userid)
```